# ASP Dropdownlist not showing in IE 9

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, c#-2.0

I am working on existing ASP.NET code and am trying to add a dialog box with 3 dropdowns. They work on my machine when debugging in IE and even when I change the IE emulated mode to 9 they show up on my machine, but when ran in IE 9 on the test server the dropdowns are not visible at all. There are no Javascript errors in the console when the page is loaded or when the button is clicked to show the dialog, and the DOM Explorer shows that the table row data has the  tag there with options inside, so I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Here is the dialogs' markup:

```
<div id="boxCreateSpare" title="Create Assembly" runat="server" style="display: none;">
        <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSpareAssemblyID" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>:
               </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selSpareAssemblyID" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblSpareDescription" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12px" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID ="lblTireProductId" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selTireProductId" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID ="lblWheelProductId" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selWheelProductId" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center" width="100%">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" style="height: 25px; width: 150px;" id="btnSpareFinishCreate" runat="server" onclick="createSpare()" />
                    <input type="button" class="button" style="height: 25px; width: 150px;" id="btnSpareCancel" runat="server" onclick="$('#boxCreateSpare').dialog('close');" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Test server IE9 dropdowns not visible:

[image: Test server IE9 dropdowns not visible]

My machine (debugging in IE emulating V9) visible:

[image: My machine (debugging in IE emulating V9) visible]

Comment: it might be a data issue on your test server, that there is no data loaded in the dropdown to show, did you try it on other browsers?

Comment: width (and other presentation) attributes are depreciated in html4...also they are in pixels not %. some bowsers will use % though. Use the DOM explorer tab of dev tools to highlight elements that appear 'hidden' when debugging presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I'm not sure what it has to do with the IE version since I'm not that well versed in IE lore, but removing the "width: 100%" style from the "asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selSpareAssemblyID"" made the selects show up. I guess what was happening was the width of the table rows were being set to 0px or something like that, but moving the "width:100" to the table made them show up. Someone might be able to go in to more detail on why this was happening, but that is how I fixed it.